# Ударение в слове "дюбель" во множественном числе.

Tags: грамотная-речь, орфоэпия

"Крепим карниз на дЮбели" или "крепим карниз на дюбелЯ"? Разные словари показывают разные ударения. Т.е. в одних правилен только первый вариант, в других же допускаются оба варианта?

Comment: @Ермакова, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

В словаре Резниченко (2010 год) указывается, что форма "дюбелЯ" употребляется только в профессиональной речи

Answer (score 0):

Дюбели, конечно.
Окончание -я в данном случае выглядит ужасным профессиональным жаргонизмом, это же не профессия такая "дюбель" по типу учитель - учителя и даже не животное вроде пудель - пудели (и пуделя). 
Сравните: китель-кители.

Интересно, а какие словари, кроме лопатинского, дают "дюбеля"?
Дело в том, что орфоэпию не стоит проверять по орфографическим словарям. И наоборот, конечно.